# array shuffling with minimum number of equal adjacent values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, shuffle

Hi i'm looking for an algorithm that, given an array as input will reshuffle it so that there will be the minimum number of equal adjacent values possible.

I'll try to explain:

```
in:[4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5] -> out: [4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5] or [5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4]
```

`in:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] -> out:` any order will do because all values are different

`in:[1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1] -> out: [1,2,1,3,1,2,3,1]` or any othrt combination with no adjacent values equal

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that `max_cnt` is the maximum number of occurrences among all elements and `n` is the size of an array.

If no element has more than `ceil(n / 2)` occurrences, it is possible to make all adjacent elements distinct because it is possible to arrange them in such a way that the distance between the elements with the same value is at least 2. Example:
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]. We can rearrange it like that: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1].
An algorithm for rearrangement is simple: put equal elements at the positions `i, i + 2, i + 4, ...` and so on.

If `max_cnt > ceil(n / 2)` positions, then you can construct the longest possible prefix with no equal adjacent elements using the algorithm described above and then fill the suffix with remaining values. Example:
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]. A prefix is [1, 2, 1, 3, 1]. The rest is filled with the remaining ones: [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]. The number of equal adjacent elements is `2 * max_cnt - n - 1`.

Comment: Good answer, but is a uniform distribution really shuffling? (I see that there is no other way to place the ones in your example, but how do you distribute, say, 4 ones randomly but not adjacent in an array of length 10?)

Comment: @MOehm According to my understanding of the question, the author wants to rearrange the array(in a deterministic way), not to shuffle it randomly(yeah, the term shuffle looks confusing in this question).

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. "Any order will do" doesn't really sound like shuffling.